# PHP id/parent, how to show all records

Tags: php, recursion

I found sample PHP code for creating JSON based on id<->parent and it looks like:

```
<?php

$rows = array(
array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'John Doe'),
array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'Sally Smith'),
array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Mike Jones'),
array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Jason Williams'),
array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Sara Johnson'),
array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'Dave Wilson'),
array('id' => 7, 'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Amy Martin'),
);
// create an index on id
$index = array();

foreach($rows as $row){
  $row['data'] = (object) [];
  $index[$row['id']] = $row;
}

// build the tree
foreach($index as $id => &$row){
  if ($id === 0) continue;
  $parent = $row['parent'];
  $index[$parent]['children'][] = &$row;
}
unset($row);

// obtain root node
$index = $index[0]['children'][0];

// output json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($index, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

it works fine but how to display all children records for specific ID? For example, I need all members for parent 2 so I try:

```
     $index = $index[2]['children'][0];
```

and it display only 3 records and it should display 4 of them (Amy Martin is missing).
Thank you.

Comment: According to your code, there are only two records for parent `2`.

Comment: @user2666909, I have checked the output of your code and run it i found also "Amy Martin" in out put. and you can't see it. can you please send the output which you want?

Comment: If you run it like this    $index = $index[2]['children'][0];    then you do not see it, but if you run it like @B. Desai said ($index = $index[2]['children']; then it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to get `0` index so only 1st hierarchy will be displayed. To access all children remove `[0]` from your data

It should be:

```
$index = $index[2]['children'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get 3 records because your 'children' are nested on different levels  (the 4th one is on a different level

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 2
            [name] => Mike Jones
       ...
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent] => 3
                            [name] => Jason Williams

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [parent] => 4
                                            [name] => Sara Johnson
                                           ...

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent] => 2
            [name] => Amy Martin
            ...

        )

)
```

In order to get all the children you need to traverse and flatten your array. This can be done using an interator.
Full code sample:

```
<?php

$rows = array(
array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'John Doe'),
array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'Sally Smith'),
array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Mike Jones'),
array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Jason Williams'),
array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Sara Johnson'),
array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'Dave Wilson'),
array('id' => 7, 'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Amy Martin'),
);
// create an index on id
$index = array();

foreach($rows as $row){
  $row['data'] = (object) [];
  $index[$row['id']] = $row;
}

// build the tree
foreach($index as $id => &$row){
  if ($id === 0) continue;
  $parent = $row['parent'];
  $index[$parent]['children'][] = &$row;
}
unset($row);

$array = $index[2]['children'];
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$data = array();

foreach ($iterator as $leafValue) {
        if ( !$iterator -> hasChildren() ) {
                if ($iterator->key() == 'id') {
                        $data[$leafValue]['id'] = $leafValue;
                        $id = $leafValue;
                } else{
                        $data[$id][$iterator->key()] = $leafValue;
                }
        }
}


// output json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output

```
{
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "parent": 2,
        "name": "Mike Jones"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "parent": 3,
        "name": "Jason Williams"
    },
    "5": {
        "id": 5,
        "parent": 4,
        "name": "Sara Johnson"
    },
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "parent": 2,
        "name": "Amy Martin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  Can not figure out how to add new line into this great Stackoverflow... :(  Two space folloved by enter does not work here ..:(

Comment: Hello, I posted new question above, regarding how to get data from MySQL into JSON.. can someone help, please? Thank you.